# ng2-page-scroll not working

Tags: angular, angular2-animation

I have a angular 2 app where I'm trying to implement a very simple animated scroll, using ng2-page-scroll.

According to the read.me, I should be able to npm install it, Import it to my module.ts file and then user the directive.

I've done all of that, but I get nothing.

Has anyone used this package and gotten it to work?

Here is my import:

```
import {Ng2PageScrollModule} from 'ng2-page-scroll/ng2-page-scroll';
```

I have it properly added in the module "import" section...

Here is my anchor link with directive:

```
 <a href="#test" pageScroll> test </a>
```

and my anchor element has id="test"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check out the <a> element in the browser using element inspector? I'm seeing a similar problem where the "pageScroll" attribute is getting converted to "pagescroll" by the time it gets to the browser. Not sure if this is expected behavior of ng serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component trying to use Ng2PageScroll is not a part of your app root module, I found that you had to add Ng2PageScrollModule to the "imports" section of the module that this component is a part of.

So for example, if you have app.module.ts which defines the root module of your app, and then you have feature-area-1.module.ts which defines a feature area module, and you want to use Ng2PageScroll in a component that is listed in the "declarations" section of the module defined in feature-area-1.module.ts, then try adding Ng2PageScrollModule to the "imports" section of the module defined in feature-area-1.module.ts.

Alternatively, try using the "Service" method [described in their documentation](https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll/tree/643faf3bf984b7dd0a1689a40631ae551dcaddb7#service) as opposed to trying to use the directives.