# Angular 16 anchor scroll troubles

Tags: scroll, fragment, href, anchor, angular16

I have a web app in angular 16 with home page with menu and several components inside which contain an id as anchor. What I want is to reach one component in the home page by clicking on a menu item.

Here are my files look like :

my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import HomeModule from './components/home/home.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

My app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent 
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My HomeComponent.html

```
<nav>
   <div class="item-menu-wrapper">
    <a [routerLink]="'/'" fragment="section1" class="item-menu">section1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="'/'" fragment="section2" class="item-menu">section2</a>
    <a [routerLink]="'/'" fragment="section3" class="item-menu">section3</a>
    <a [routerLink]="'/'" fragment="section4" class="item-menu">section4</a>
   </div>
</nav>

<div>
    <app-landing-page></app-landing-page>
    <app-section1></app-section1>
    <app-section2></app-section2>
    <app-section3></app-section3>
    <app-section4></app-section4>
</div>
```

One of my section component

```
<div>
    <h1 id="section1">This is my section</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum....</p>
</div>
```

Each section is a standalone component with his own module which is imported in the home.module.ts.

What I tried to do but doesn't work :

- use 'href= "#section1"'
- use ngx-page-scroll package [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821468/ng2-page-scroll-not-working)
  but seems last angular 16 update is not supported

My last solution is what you can see above by using fragments. I follow many threads
[like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836497/using-html-anchor-link-fragment-in-angular-6)
[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906092/href-with-id-of-dom-element-is-not-working-with-angular)

Have I missed something ? Why anything works ?

Thanks in advance for your help